# mysql double insert to two different tables

Tags: mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Mysql insert into 2 tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3053593/mysql-insert-into-2-tables)

is it possible to make this?

e.g. INSERT INTO tableA,tableB VALUES (sharedVal, valA) (sharedVal, valB)

Comment: Please search the site before asking your questions, to see if someone has already asked it. Especially for something so straightforward as this.

Answer (score 0):

this is not posible

you can do something like :

```
begin transaction
 Insert into table1(col1, col2, col3 ) values v1, v2, v3;
 Insert into table2(col1, col2, col3 ) values v1, v2, v3 ;
  commit
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply

```
 $sql1 = "INSERT INTO tableA (shareda, vala) VALUES (sharedVal, valA)";
 $sql2 = "INSERT INTO tableB (sharedb, valb) VALUES (sharedVal, valB)";
```

Each time you should specify the table column, where you're putting your values.