# Inserting multiple records with pg-promise

Tags: node.js, postgresql, pg-promise

I have a scenario in which I need to insert multiple records. I have a table structure like id (it's fk from other table), key(char), value(char). The input which needs to be saved would be array of above data. example:
I have some array objects like:

```js
lst = [];

obj = {};
obj.id= 123;
obj.key = 'somekey';
obj.value = '1234';
lst.push(obj);

obj = {};
obj.id= 123;
obj.key = 'somekey1';
obj.value = '12345';
lst.push(obj);
```

In MS SQL, I would have created TVP and passed it. I don't know how to achieve in postgres.
So now what I want to do is save all the items from the list in single query in postgres sql, using pg-promise library. I'm not able to find any documentation / understand from documentation. Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: 1. Are all records being inserted into the same table? 2. When you say in one query - do you actually mean a single SQL query or in one operation?

Comment: I meant in same query. Simply like how we just pass data to TVP and insert it into table by selecting from TVP. All data goes in same table.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

I am the author of [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise).

There are two ways to insert multiple records. The first, and most typical way is via a transaction, to make sure all records are inserted correctly, or none of them.

With [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise) it is done in the following way:

```
db.tx(t => {
    const queries = lst.map(l => {
        return t.none('INSERT INTO table(id, key, value) VALUES(${id}, ${key}, ${value})', l);
    });
    return t.batch(queries);
})
    .then(data => {
        // SUCCESS
        // data = array of null-s
    })
    .catch(error => {
        // ERROR
    });
```

You initiate a transaction with method [tx](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/Database.html#tx), then create all `INSERT` query promises, and then resolve them all as a [batch](http://vitaly-t.github.io/spex/global.html#batch).

The second approach is by concatenating all insert values into a single `INSERT` query, which I explain in detail in [Performance Boost](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise/wiki/Performance-Boost). See also: [Multi-row insert with pg-promise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37300997/multi-row-insert-with-pg-promise).

For more examples see [Tasks](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise/wiki/Learn-by-Example#tasks) and [Transactions](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise/wiki/Learn-by-Example#transactions).

**Addition**

It is worth pointing out that in most cases we do not insert a record `id`, rather have it generated automatically. Sometimes we want to get the new id-s back, and in other cases we don't care.

The examples above resolve with an array of `null`-s, because [batch](http://vitaly-t.github.io/spex/global.html#batch) resolves with an array of individual results, and method [none](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/Database.html#none) resolves with `null`, according to its API.

Let's assume that we want to generate the new id-s, and that we want to get them all back. To accomplish this we would change the code to the following:

```
db.tx(t => {
    const queries = lst.map(l => {
        return t.one('INSERT INTO table(key, value) VALUES(${key}, ${value}) RETURNING id',
                       l, a => +a.id);
    });
    return t.batch(queries);
})
    .then(data => {
        // SUCCESS
        // data = array of new id-s;
    })
    .catch(error => {
        // ERROR
    });
```

i.e. the changes are:

- we do not insert the `id` values
- we replace method [none](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/Database.html#none) with [one](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/Database.html#one), to get one row/object from each insert
- we append `RETURNING id` to the query to get the value
- we add `a => +a.id` to do the automatic row transformation. See also [pg-promise returns integers as strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39168501/pg-promise-returns-integers-as-strings) to understand what that `+` is for.

**UPDATE-1**

For a high-performance approach via a single `INSERT` query see [Multi-row insert with pg-promise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37300997/multi-row-insert-with-pg-promise).

**UPDATE-2**

A must-read article: [Data Imports](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise/wiki/Data-Imports).

Comment: Thank you. I will check it out. I'm waiting for more answers though .. else would mark your answer as final if everything works as I want ;)

Comment: @Mandy LOL, I am the author of pg-promise :)

Comment: oops I didn't notice it ;) thanks. :D . It's great module ^_^

Comment: @Mandy The **Addition** may prove helpful ;)

Comment: in my case I don't need IDs. but someone else might find it very useful for sure :-)

Comment: @Mandy I have added an update with the most recent question that's directly related, and offers a much better performance.

Comment: @vitaly-t any guidance on how to use helpers.insert with RETURNING?

Comment: @Sam see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41955767/how-to-return-insert-query-result-values-using-pg-promise-helpers

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Very well written answer.

Comment: @deb_ Thanks, but I think [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37300997/multi-row-insert-with-pg-promise) is a better answer (more practically useful).

Comment: @vitaly-t Thanks for your response. The helpers namespace example is the preferred way to go. Cheers :-)