# How to return insert query result values using pg-promise helpers

Tags: node.js, postgresql, pg-promise

I am using [pgp.helpers.insert](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/helpers.html#.insert) to save data into PostgreSQL which is working well. However, I need to return values to present in a response. I am using:

```
this.collection.one(this.collection.$config.pgp.helpers.insert(values, null, 'branch'))
```

which returns no data.

What I want to be able to do is return the branch id after a successful insert, such as:

```
INSERT into branch (columns) VALUES (values) RETURNING pk_branchID
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simply append the `RETURNING...` clause to the generated query:

```
const h = this.collection.$config.pgp.helpers;
const query = h.insert(values, null, 'branch') + 'RETURNING pk_branchID';
      
await this.collection.one(query);
```

You must have a large object there, if you want to automatically generate the insert. Namespace [helpers](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/helpers.html) is mostly valued when generating multi-row inserts/updates, in which case a [ColumnSet](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/helpers.ColumnSet.html) is used as a static variable:

```
const h = this.collection.$config.pgp.helpers;
const cs = new h.ColumnSet(['col_a', 'col_b'], {table: 'branch'});
const data = [{col_a: 1, col_b: 2}, ...];

const query = h.insert(data, cs) + 'RETURNING pk_branchID';
      
await this.collection.many(query);
```

Note that in this case, we do [.many](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/Database.html#many), as 1 or more rows/results are expected back. This can even be transformed into just an array of id-s:

```
await this.collection.map(query, [], a => a.pk_branchID);
```

see: [Database.map](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/Database.html#map)

Comment: Thank you.  Originally, I had the SQL in a file but thought to use this way in order to cater for column values that can be null that may be missing from the request.