# Function calling insert operation using pg-promise executes without any success or error message

Tags: javascript, node.js, pg-promise

I have a function `bulkInsert()` which performs an insert operation using pg-promise and when I call it using the `await` keyword, it executes without any result (success/error). I am not sure if I am missing anything. Any help is appreciated.

```
const pgp = require('pg-promise');
const db = pgp({
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 5443,
    database: 'data_base',
    user: 'user_name',
    password: 'pass_word',
});
.......
.......
.......
const bulkInsert = async (data) => { //function when called, executes without any result(success/failure)

    const cs = new pgp.helpers.ColumnSet(['col_A', 'col_B','col_C'], { table: 'table_name' });

    db.tx('massive-insert', t => {
        const processData = data => {
            if (data) {
                const insert = pgp.helpers.insert(data, cs);
                return t.none(insert);
            }
        };
        return t.sequence(index => getNextData(t, index, data).then(processData));
    })
        .then(() => {
            console.log('Success');
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        });

    function getNextData(t, pageIndex, data) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            const batchSize = 1000;
            const nextDataBatch = [];
            try{
                for (let i = pageIndex; i < data.length; i += batchSize) {
                    const batch = data.slice(i, i + batchSize);
                    nextDataBatch.push(batch);
                }

                if (nextDataBatch.length === 0) {
                    resolve(null);
                } else {
                    resolve(nextDataBatch);
                }
            }
            catch(err){
                reject(err);
            }
        });
    }

};
```

PS: I am using pg-promise v11.5.4 and in node v18.17.1

Comment: Using `await` for `bulkInsert` does nothing, because that function doesn't return anything. What you are missing is basic understanding how promises work, and chaining their results. Not really relevant to `pg-promise`.

Comment: @vitaly-t I am new to javascript/nodejs. Can you please let me know, what exactly I missing here.

Comment: This link will be helped you. [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36233566/inserting-multiple-records-with-pg-promise)

Comment: @Nikitashrama I tried to implement the code snippet from that link as well, but same result.

Comment: Why does `getNextData` return a promise? Nothing is asynchronous in there.

Comment: @Bergi I tried to implement what was mentioned in 
https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise/wiki/Data-Imports#massive-inserts

Comment: @artificialunintelligence That does not apply to you. You do not have a "*situation when your data cannot be fully inside the process*". You're not loading the data step by step from some stream - you're passing a single `data` array to your function. Really you should use the [bog-standard `insert` method](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise/wiki/Data-Imports#example)

Comment: @Bergi I tried that as well, but same result.

Comment: Yes, do that, it's much simpler. Of course, you're still not `return`ing a promise from `bulkInsert`, so you still cannot `await bulkInsert(…)`.

Comment: @Bergi Yes, I am not using await now. But my point is even after using the standard insert method, I am not able to produce any result(success/failure). As Vitaly-t mentioned, it might be something related to how I am chaining the promise, but not sure what exactly I am missing out.

Comment: Again, you are missing the `return` statement. `bulkInsert(…)` returns `undefined`.

Comment: @Bergi Thank you so much for your insights. I am able to perform the insert operation now.