# What is the proper way to insert data to multiple separate tables when inserting into a table?

Tags: postgresql, function, stored-procedures, triggers, sql-insert

For example I have a table called `product_list`, which holds a list of products.

If I insert 1 row of data into `product_list`, part of the data (such as `product_id` & `product name`) should also be inserted in another table like `product_price` which holds the price for all products (new products would have 0 or NULL values for their price).

My question here is the method in approaching this. What is the proper way to do this?

My current ideas:

#### 1 - Using a trigger to insert into the other tables like `product_price`,etc whenever I insert a product data into `product_list`

#### 2 - Using a function (stored procedure) like `product_add` to add a new product into each tables.

Which method is better? Or if there a better suggestion, then I'd like to know about it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you edit your question and give us the structure of yout two tables

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Insert data in 3 tables at a time using Postgres](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20561254/insert-data-in-3-tables-at-a-time-using-postgres)