# Postgresql: How to make multiple inserts using one select

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-insert

```
WITH migration (first_name , middle_name , last_name,fourth_name,
secondary_school ,faculty_id,department_id,university_id,name ) AS (
    SELECT first_name , middle_name , last_name,fourth_name,
    secondary_school ,faculty,department ,university_id , 
    concat(first_name,' ', middle_name,' ', last_name,' ', fourth_name) AS name 
    From student_migration ),
insert1 AS 
(
   insert into res_users(name ,login ,password)
   SELECT name, university_id,university_id FROM migration   -- DISTINCT? see below
   RETURNING id AS user_id
),
insert2 AS 
(
    insert into uni_student (first_name , middle_name , last_name,fourth_name,
    secondary_school ,faculty_id,department_id,university_id,name)
    SELECT first_name , middle_name , last_name,fourth_name,
    secondary_school ,faculty_id,department_id,university_id,name
)
```

I am trying to make insert1 and insert2 using data on migration and insert2 it depends on insert1 on returning value user_id. I am trying to use the script shown above but it throws a syntax error

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near ";" LINE 19:  FROM   migration
>   RETURNING id AS partner_id);
>                                                         ^
>   ********** Error **********
>
> ERROR: syntax error at or near ";" SQL state: 42601 Character: 851

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: using above script am trying to insert data on res_users then on uni_student by passing user_id that created on first inset .. but it did't working for me ERROR:  syntax error at or near ";"
LINE 19:  FROM   migration RETURNING id AS partner_id);
                                                      ^
********** Error **********

ERROR: syntax error at or near ";"
SQL state: 42601
Character: 851

Comment: With a FUNCTION, perhaps?

Comment: A CTE must end with a "regular" statement. Yours doesn't have one. You are also missing a `FROM` clause in the last SELECT statement

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add some [sample data](http://plaintexttools.github.io/plain-text-table/) and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [**no screen shots**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). **[edit]** your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Insert data in 3 tables at a time using Postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20561254/insert-data-in-3-tables-at-a-time-using-postgres)