# How to generate a single new row from a multi-row update in a trigger?

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-design, triggers

Basically I have a few different tables which share an array field `job_ids` and each has their own `status` which is also an integer. On the `job` table, `id` is its primary key.

Postgres version 12.5

Table `table1`:

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (
id serial NOT NULL,
jobs_ids _int4 NULL,
status int4 NULL,
CONSTRAINT cable_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
```

Table `job`:

```
CREATE TABLE job (
id serial NOT NULL,
description varchar NULL,
created_at timestamptz NULL DEFAULT now(),
modified_at timestamptz NULL DEFAULT now(),
CONSTRAINT job_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
```

My trigger function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION new_job_id_table1()
 RETURNS trigger
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
BEGIN

if new.status= 3 and new.jobs_ids = '{}' then 
   insert into job (description, type_id)
   select 'automated jobid with id=' || new.id, 1;

   new.jobs_ids := array[ max(b.id) ] from job b
   where new.jobs_ids = '{}' and b.type_id  = 1;
end if;
RETURN NEW; 

END;
$function$;
```

Trigger, set to run before update:

```
create trigger job_id_trigger_table1
before update of status on table1
for each row execute function new_job_id_table1();
```

Users update stuff through qgis but usually it's:

```
update table1 set status = 3 where id = $whatever_id_they_picked;
```

It creates a new entry in the `job` table and assigns that `id` to the updated row in `table1`.

It works fine if the user updates one row in `table1` to status 3. However, it does nothing when a user updates multiple rows at a time.
If multiple rows are updated at once, I would like to generate only *one* job id for to several rows in `table1` instead of (currently) multiple.

How to make the trigger work with multi-row updates?

Comment: Please provide a valid `CREATE TABLE` script showing data types and constraints, instead of the prose about said table. The first is perfectly useful, the second not so much. And always your version of Postgres.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter I've edited the op

Comment: I see a function definition, but no trigger definition. Also "user updates feature" is an unclear definition. What "feature"? `UPDATE`? `INSERT`? What's "at the same time" exactly? In the same command? All too vague.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter editted again

Answer (score 0):

#### Setup

First I simplified and improved your test setup:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table1 (
  id        serial PRIMARY KEY
, jobs_ids  int4[]
, status    int4 NOT NULL  -- !
);

-- DROP TABLE job;
CREATE TABLE job (
  id           serial PRIMARY KEY
, type_id      int NOT NULL DEFAULT 1  -- was missing
, description  varchar
, created_at   timestamptz DEFAULT now()
, modified_at  timestamptz DEFAULT now()
);
```

Also straightened out your original trigger to understand what's going on. You might use this as fallback if the solution below is not for you:

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=f2266e299f7e75235bcb378ef37c29fe)*

#### Solution

Using an [**`AFTER`** trigger with **transition tables**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtrigger.html).

Trigger function:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION job_id_trigger_table1()
  RETURNS trigger
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
BEGIN
   WITH sel AS (
      SELECT n.id
      FROM   updated_new n
      JOIN   updated_old o USING (id)  -- never update id!
      WHERE  n.status = 3
      AND    o.status <> 3
      AND    n.jobs_ids = '{}'
      )
   , ins AS (
      INSERT INTO job (description, type_id)
      SELECT 'automated jobid for IDs ' || array_agg(s.id)::text, 1
      FROM   sel s
      HAVING count(*) > 0  -- skip all if no matching rows
      RETURNING id
      )
    UPDATE table1 t
    SET    jobs_ids = ARRAY[i.id]
    FROM   sel s, ins i
    WHERE  t.id = s.id;
      
   RETURN NULL;  -- for AFTER trigger
END
$func$;
```

Trigger:

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER job_id_trigger_table1
AFTER UPDATE ON table1
REFERENCING OLD TABLE AS updated_old
            NEW TABLE AS updated_new
FOR EACH STATEMENT
WHEN (pg_trigger_depth() = 0)  -- only immediate update!
EXECUTE FUNCTION job_id_trigger_table1();
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=270f52b4c885277ae1f975cab17e783e)*

This **creates a single row in `job`** for any number of (qualifying!) rows updated in a single command.

I inspect both `OLD` and `NEW` transition relations to make sure to only fire after status was actually changed in the update. If you don't need this, remove the `OLD` relation.

Unfortunately, we cannot restrict to `UPDATE OF status` right away, as that is [currently not implemented](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtrigger.html):

> The standard allows transition tables to be used with column-specific
> `UPDATE` triggers, but then the set of rows that should be visible in
> the transition tables depends on the trigger's column list. This is
> not currently implemented by PostgreSQL.

I join `OLD` to `NEW` transition relation `USING id`. Creates a corner case where this can go wrong after updating `table1.id`. Typically, that never happens, but take precautions.

To avoid an update loop, I added `WHEN (pg_trigger_depth() = 0)` to the trigger. See:

- [How to prevent a PostgreSQL trigger from being fired by another trigger?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/103661/3684)

The function only uses a single DDL statement with (data-modifying) CTEs. Should be most efficient. See:

- [Insert data in 3 tables at a time using Postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20561627/939860)

If no qualifying rows are found, `INSERT` and `UPDATE` are skipped. Nothing happens.

I added a couple of tests to the fiddle to verify it works as advertised.