# Data insertion into multiple tables with one query using postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-insert, common-table-expression, postgresql-9.3

I want to insert data into multiple related tables in one go - in a single transaction. I am using Postgres and Dapper ORM. Here is my query:

```
WITH userins AS (
    INSERT INTO public."user"
(
    "FirstName", 
    "LastName", 
    "Email", 
    "PasswordHash", 
    "Address", 
    "City", 
    "State", 
    "Zip", 
    "Phone", 
    "IsEnabled", 
    "IsVerified", 
    "IsDeleted",  
    "CreatedDate", 
)
    VALUES (@FirstName, @LastName, @Email, @PasswordHash, @Address, @City, @State, @Zip, @Phone, @IsEnabled, ?IsVerified, ?IsDeleted, @CreatedDate);
    RETURNING id AS user_id
   )
, clientins AS (
    INSERT INTO public.client( "Description", "PlanCustomerId", "IsActive", "IsDeleted", "CreatedBy", "CreatedDate", userid)
                           VALUES(@Description, @PlanCustomerId, @IsActive,@IsDeleted, user_id, @CreatedDate,user_id) RETURNING id as client_id;
   )
   , clientsubins
   (
    INSERT INTO public.client_subscription(
    "PlanId", 
    "IsActive",
    "StartDate", 
    "EndDate", 
    "IsDeleted", 
    "CreatedBy", 
    "CreatedDate", 
    clientid, 
    subscriptionid)
    VALUES (@PlanId, @IsActive, @StartDate, @EndDate, @IsDeleted, user_id, @CreatedDate, client_id, @subscriptionid);
   )
   RETURNING client_id
```

Will this query work or what I need to change?

Comment: This is not the normal way to deal with transactions

Comment: Can you please let me know which way is good

Comment: You might want to checkout Transactions? This question might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5178697/mysql-insert-into-multiple-tables-database-normalization

Comment: Urgently consider upgrading to [a current version of Postgres](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/). Version 9.3 has reached EOL in 2018 (!)

Comment: @ShaileshSuryawanshi: Why would you link to a MySQL question? This is Postgres with different (superior) transaction handling. And `LAST_INSERT_ID()` (as suggested over there) is MySQL-specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

postgreSql has different syntax for that. I was stuck in this also a few days back figured out how to deal with it. You can user **BEGIN** block to insert data into multiple tables for that you please follow this query and your work will be done.

```
BEGIN;
                WITH userins AS (
                INSERT INTO public.user(
                ""FirstName"", ""LastName"", ""Email"", ""PasswordHash"",""VerificationCode"", ""Phone"", ""IsEnabled"", ""IsVerified"", ""IsDeleted"",  ""CreatedDate"")VALUES(@FirstName, @LastName, @Email, @PasswordHash, @VerificationCode, @Phone, @IsEnabled, @IsVerified, @IsDeleted, @CreatedDate)
                    RETURNING id AS user_id)
                ,clientins AS(
                INSERT INTO public.client(""Description"", ""PlanCustomerId"", ""IsActive"", ""IsDeleted"", ""CreatedBy"", ""CreatedDate"", UserId) 
                        VALUES(@Description, @PlanCustomerId, @IsActive, @IsDeleted, (SELECT user_id from userins), @CreatedDate, (SELECT user_id from userins)) RETURNING id as client_id)
                ,clientsubins AS
                (
                   INSERT INTO public.client_subscription(""PlanId"", ""IsActive"",""StartDate"", ""EndDate"", ""IsDeleted"", ""CreatedBy"", ""CreatedDate"", ClientId, SubscriptionId)
                   VALUES(@PaymentMethodPlanId, @IsActive, @StartDate, @EndDate, @IsDeleted, (SELECT user_id from userins), @CreatedDate, (SELECT client_id from clientins), @PlanId)
                )
                ,clientpurchaseins AS
                (
                   INSERT INTO public.client_purchase_history(""PlanId"", ""InvoiceId"",""StartDate"", ""EndDate"", ""IsDeleted"", ""CreatedBy"", ""CreatedDate"", ClientId)
                   VALUES(@PlanId, @InvoiceId, @StartDate, @EndDate, @IsDeleted, (SELECT user_id from userins), @CreatedDate, (SELECT client_id FROM clientins))
                )
                SELECT client_id from clientins;
        COMMIT;
```

Here is Begin block will take care of your transaction if there is any error occurred then it will be rollback automatically.

Answer (score 2):

The answers you have received are good, however I will give my recommendation. Since you are dealing with a block of transactions, it is better to include that as part of a function or stored procedure.  For exammple, I prefer to assign the returning id in a variable, that way I can use it across the execution. If everything is ok, I commit and  return the user_id or I can also change the return type to boolean if required. If there is an exception, I catch it and return -1, indicating it was not successful, here you can also perform other options, such as registering in a table the cause of the exception. If one table fails, all is rolled back:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test_function(p_name CHAR(50), p_other_params CHAR(50)) 
RETURNS INT AS
$$
DECLARE
  new_user_id INT;
  new_purchase_id INT;
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO public.user(name)
    VALUES(p_name) 
    RETURNING public.user.id INTO new_user_id;
    
    INSERT INTO public.purchase(user_id)
    VALUES(new_user_id) 
    RETURNING public.purchase.id INTO new_purchase_id;
    
     INSERT INTO public.purchase_detail(purchase_id)
    VALUES(new_purchase_id);
    
    RAISE EXCEPTION 'Exception when inserting user: %', p_name; --remove to test when there is no issue
    --commited if reaches this point
    RETURN new_user_id;
    
    EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
    --ROLLED back if exception
    RETURN -1; -- this value indicates the app it failed
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
          
 select * from test_function('SomeName', 'OtherParameter');
 select id, name from public.user;
 select id, user_id from public.purchase;
 select id, purchase_id from public.purchase_detail;
```

This is the schema:

```
CREATE TABLE public.user(  name CHAR(50)); 
CREATE TABLE public.purchase( user_id int);
CREATE TABLE public.purchase_detail( purchase_id INT);
ALTER TABLE public.user ADD COLUMN id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY;
ALTER TABLE public.purchase ADD COLUMN id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY;
ALTER TABLE public.purchase_detail ADD COLUMN id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY;
```

Check [this fiddle in action,](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/poGf4FLC4u4UiS33Ga8qu9/2) and remember to remove the RAISE Exception line to test when there is no exception.
Note: For some reason, in fiddle the $$ should be replaces by quotes, and therefore single quotes inside are double quoted.

More on [exception handling](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/plpgsql-control-structures.html) (40.6.6. Trapping Errors).

Answer (score 1):

Most importantly, you need to `SELECT` from earlier CTEs to get to the values resulting from the `RETURNING` clause:

```sql
WITH userins AS (
   INSERT INTO public."user"
          ("FirstName", "LastName", "Email", "PasswordHash", "Address", "City", "State", "Zip", "Phone", "IsEnabled", "IsVerified", "IsDeleted", "CreatedDate") --  no dangling ,
   VALUES (@FirstName , @LastName , @Email , @PasswordHash , @Address , @City , @State , @Zip , @Phone , @IsEnabled , @IsVerified , @IsDeleted , @CreatedDate)  --  no ;
   RETURNING id AS userid
   )
 , clientins AS (
   INSERT INTO public.client
         ("Description", "PlanCustomerId", "IsActive", "IsDeleted", "CreatedBy", "CreatedDate", userid)
   SELECT @Description , @PlanCustomerId , @IsActive , @IsDeleted , userid     , @CreatedDate , userid
   FROM   userins
   RETURNING id AS clientid, userid  -- no ;
   )
INSERT INTO public.client_subscription
      ("PlanId", "IsActive","StartDate", "EndDate", "IsDeleted", "CreatedBy", "CreatedDate", clientid , subscriptionid)
SELECT @PlanId , @IsActive , @StartDate, @EndDate , @IsDeleted , userid     , @CreatedDate , clientid,  @subscriptionid
FROM   clientins
RETURNING clientid;
```

You also had a couple of syntax errors. And I unified the spelling of `clientid` etc.

Each CTE (and the outer `INSERT`) depends on the one resulting row from the preceding CTE. This way, nothing is inserted if the first `INSERT` does not insert (and return) anything.

Since this is a *single* statement, it runs inside a single transaction automatically. Any error cancels the whole operation.

Even works in your outdated Postgres 9.3.

See:

- [Insert data in 3 tables at a time using Postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20561254/insert-data-in-3-tables-at-a-time-using-postgres/20561627#20561627)