# Executing Multiple SQL Statements in Go using pgx

Tags: postgresql, go, pgx

Will this work with `pgx` in Go?

```
func CreateTable(
    ctx context.Context,
    pgxPool *pgxpool.Pool,
) error {
    const tableQuery = `
        INSERT INTO table (status) 
        VALUES ('Active');

        INSERT INTO table_updates (status)
        VALUES ('Active');
    `

    err := utilities.PerformExec(ctx, pgxPool, tableQuery, "CreateTable")
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    return nil
}
```

And this is the `PerformExec` function.

```
func PerformExec(ctx context.Context, pgxPool *pgxpool.Pool, query, origin string, args ...interface{}) error {
    _, err := pgxPool.Exec(ctx, query, args...)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return nil
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your reason to do this in single query is to avoid unnecessary network roundtrips then look at `pgx.Batch`.

See example here:
https://github.com/jackc/pgx/blob/c1b0a01ca75ac9eb3a7dbc1396f583ab5dbf9557/batch_test.go#L34

---

Apparently you can craft a single postgresql query that inserts into multiple tables - [Refer answers here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20561254/insert-data-in-3-tables-at-a-time-using-postgres). But IMO `pgx.Batch` is much readable solution.

Comment: Yes, I personally checked, and it works. Thanks for your time and assistance.