# Rewrite Select SQL query for PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.1, postgresql-9.3

I created these tables in PostgreSQL based on this topic :

[Database design for user settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10204902/database-design-for-user-settings)

```
-- TABLE SETTING

CREATE TABLE SETTING(
 ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
 DESCRIPTION TEXT,
 CONSTRAINED TEXT,
 DATA_TYPE TEXT,
 MIN_VALUE TEXT,
 MAX_VALUE TEXT
)
;

-- ADD KEYS FOR TABLE SETTING

ALTER TABLE SETTING ADD CONSTRAINT KEY34 PRIMARY KEY (ID)
;

-- TABLE ALLOWED_SETTING_VALUE

CREATE TABLE ALLOWED_SETTING_VALUE(
 ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
 SETTING_ID INTEGER,
 ITEM_VALUE TEXT,
 CAPTION TEXT
)
;

-- CREATE INDEXES FOR TABLE ALLOWED_SETTING_VALUE

CREATE INDEX IX_RELATIONSHIP16 ON ALLOWED_SETTING_VALUE (SETTING_ID)
;

-- ADD KEYS FOR TABLE ALLOWED_SETTING_VALUE

ALTER TABLE ALLOWED_SETTING_VALUE ADD CONSTRAINT KEY35 PRIMARY KEY (ID)
;

-- TABLE USER_SETTING

CREATE TABLE USER_SETTING(
 ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
 USER_ID INTEGER,
 SETTING_ID INTEGER,
 ALLOWED_SETTING_VALUE_ID INTEGER,
 UNCONSTRAINED_VALUE TEXT
)
;

-- CREATE INDEXES FOR TABLE USER_SETTING

CREATE INDEX IX_RELATIONSHIP15 ON USER_SETTING (SETTING_ID)
;

CREATE INDEX IX_RELATIONSHIP17 ON USER_SETTING (ALLOWED_SETTING_VALUE_ID)
;

-- ADD KEYS FOR TABLE USER_SETTING

ALTER TABLE USER_SETTING ADD CONSTRAINT KEY36 PRIMARY KEY (ID)
;
```

But when I run Select SQL query I get error because it's for MySQL:

```
-- Show settings for a given user
select
  US.user_id 
, S1.description 
, S1.data_type 
, case when S1.constrained = 'true'
  then AV.item_value
  else US.unconstrained_value
  end value
, AV.caption
from USER_SETTING US
  inner join SETTING S1
    on US.setting_id = S1.id 
  left outer join ALLOWED_SETTING_VALUE AV
    on US.allowed_setting_value_id = AV.id
where US.user_id = 234
```

***result***

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "value"
LINE 8:   end value
```

Howe I can rewrite this SQL query for PostgreSQL?

Comment: This is valid Standard SQL, try adding `AS`:  `AS value` (I just tried it on Fiddle and this worked). Seems to be a weird parsing error.

Comment: Yes, this solves the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`value` is a reserved keyword, you need to quote it in SQL:

```
case when S1.constrained = 'true'
    then AV.item_value
    else US.unconstrained_value
end "value"
```

Adding the `as` keyword works, because this remove the ambiguity what `value` might be. But it's still better to quote it - even when using the `as` keyword (or find a different name).

[This behaviour is documented](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-select-lists.html#QUERIES-COLUMN-LABELS) and the manual explicitly mentions the keyword `value`

> The AS keyword is optional, but only if the new column name does not match any PostgreSQL keyword (see Appendix C). To avoid an accidental match to a keyword, you can double-quote the column name. For example, VALUE is a keyword, so this does not work:
>
> `SELECT a value, b + c AS sum FROM ...`
>
> but this does:
>
> SELECT a "value", b + c AS sum FROM ...
>
> For protection against possible future keyword additions, it is recommended that you always either write AS or double-quote the output column name.

---

Unrelated, but:

You shouldn't store boolean values (`true`, `false`)  in a `text` column. Postgres has a native `boolean` data type for this.