# Storing API configuration

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, settings

I am building an API that consumes a AWS lambda. There are some settings (e.g. default values that API uses). I know I can store them to database and then based on the user logged in I can call an API that returns the settings for that user...
However, I was wondering if there is a better way to this without using database tables. Does amazon has any way/place where you can store this settings and then pass it to the API when it is called?
If amazon doesn't have such a thing, what is a good practice to store user settings  on APIs?

Comment: aws provide data storing services which you can use. But it is same as storing data in ur own database. As for good practice.. you can check this... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10204902/database-design-for-user-settings

Comment: Can you name any service amazon offers that can be used for settings?

Comment: Does the settings change for each user remain constant?

Comment: @DoArNa services like aurora, documentdb, dynamodb, RDS etc.. you can access all these from lambda function

Comment: @OluwafemiSule yes they are different for each user

Comment: @DoArNa, I would suggest a DynamoDB table for your use case. AcDynamoDB table is a key value storage. And it is not like relational databases (eg- MySQL) that you need to maintain a table schema. Based on the requirements you mentioned in this post, I would consider DynamoDB as the first option.