# mysql - insert many to many relationship

Tags: mysql, insert, many-to-many

I am trying to insert records in 2 different mysql tables. Here's the situation:

Table 1: `is_main` that contains records of resorts with a primary key called `id`.

Table 2: `is_features` that contains a list of features that a resort can have (i.e. beach, ski, spa etc...). Each feature has got a primary key called `id`.

Table 3: `is_i2f` to connect each resort id with the feature id. This table has got 2 fields: `id_i` and `id_f`. Both fields are primary key.

I have created a form to insert a new resort, but I'm stuck here. I need a proper mysql query to insert a new resort in the `is_main` table and insert in `is_i2f` one record for each feature it has, with the id of the resort id `id_i` and the id of the feature id `id_f`.

```
$features = ['beach','relax','city_break','theme_park','ski','spa','views','fine_dining','golf'];

mysql_query("INSERT INTO is_main (inv_name, armchair, holiday, sipp, resort, price, rooms, inv_length, more_info)
VALUES ('$name', '$armchair', '$holiday', '$sipp', '$resort', '$price', '$rooms', '$length', '$more_info')");

$id = mysql_insert_id();

foreach($features as $feature) {
    if(isset($_POST[$feature])) {
        $$feature = 1;
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO is_i2f (id_i, id_f) VALUES (" . $id . ", ?????????????? /missing part here????/ ); }
    else {
        $$feature = 0; }
}
```

Thanks.
Please, I'm going CrAzY!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

This may not be relevant to you, but...

Would it not make more sense to leave the link table unpopulated?  You can use `JOIN`s to then select what you need to populate the various views etc in your application

i.e. query to get 1 resort with all features:

```
SELECT
    Id,
    f.Id,
    f.Name
FROM IS_MAIN m
CROSS JOIN IS_FEATURES f
WHERE m.Id = $RequiredResortId
```

Answer (score 0):

Please find the answer on [Mysql insert into 2 tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3053593/mysql-insert-into-2-tables).

If you want to do multiple insert at a time you can write a SP to fulfill your needs

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you could concatenate variable amount of to be inserted/selected values into one query. (This is the second query which needs an `id` from the first.)

```
//initializing variables
$id = mysql_insert_id();
$qTail = '';
$i = -1;

//standard beginning
$qHead = "INSERT INTO `is_i2f` (`id`,`feature`) VALUES ";

  //loop through variable amount of variables
  foreach($features] as $key => $feature) {
    $i++;

    //id stays the same, $feature varies
    $qValues[$i] = "('{$id}', '{$feature}')";

    //multiple values into one string
    $qTail .= $qValues[$i] . ',';

  } //end of foreach

//concatenate working query, need to remove last comma from $qTail
$q = $qHead . rtrim($qTail, ',');
```

Now you should have a usable `insert` query `$q`. Just `echo` it and see how it looks and test if it works.

Hope this was the case. If not, sorry...