# Insert parentId automatically to child table in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables, one is parent and another one is child. Parent table has a field called "parent_id" (primary key) and child table has a field called "parent_id"(foreign key) so there are link together. 
If I insert a row into the parent table and at same time I also want to insert a row into child table with the same parent id in the parent_id field. How to do this?

Comment: Is `parent.parent_id` an auto increment field?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mysql insert into 2 tables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3053593/mysql-insert-into-2-tables)

Comment: If there is a foreign key constraint established, before inserting an entry into child table you have to make sure that the corresponding parent entry exists in the parent table. If you don't have a parent entry, and still trying to insert a child entry, what's the point in having a foreign key constraint, right?

Comment: If you want to insert an entry into a child table which has a foreign key to parent table's entry, within a single statement, you can write a stored procedure and call that procedure when you would wish to insert the entries.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write  a stored procedure.
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-procedure.html