# how to insert data into 2 different tables (php mysql)

Tags: php, mysql, database, sql-insert

2 Tables:

**1. BOOKS_IN**

- BOOKS_in_ID,
- DATE,
- USERID

**2. BOOKS_IN_DETAIL**

- BOOKS_in_ID,
- BOOK_ID,
- STOCK

BOOKS_in_ID is a primary key and i need BOOKS_in_ID is automatically insert into BOOKS_IN_DETAIL.
Here, is it possible to insert records into 2 table using single query?

thankyou for your advise.

Comment: No, it's not. But you can call the last inserted id and use that in a second insert

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mysql insert into 2 tables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3053593/mysql-insert-into-2-tables)

Comment: You should edit your question to add what you tried so far.

Answer (score 1):

You still need two `INSERT` statements, but it sounds like you want to get the `IDENTITY` from the first insert and use it in the second, in which case, you might want to look into `OUTPUT` or `OUTPUT INTO`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx

Src and possible duplicate of: [SQL Server: Is it possible to insert into two tables at the same time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/175066/sql-server-is-it-possible-to-insert-into-two-tables-at-the-same-time)

You can also use `LastInsertId()` for PDO.

A small example:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO city (`city`) VALUES ('Paris') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `city` = 'Paris"; 
$dbh->query($sql); 
echo $dbh->lastInsertId();
```

Src: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php

Or get the last insert ID in mysqli:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO myCity VALUES (NULL, 'Stuttgart', 'DEU', 'Stuttgart', 617000)";
$mysqli->query($query);

printf ("New Record has id %d.\n", $mysqli->insert_id);
```

Src: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php

Comment: because the question is related to php and mysql, not SQL Server

Answer (score 1):

You need to call the appropriate method to get the last inserted id.

Assuming you use `PDO`, you need to call the method lastInsertId. `$books_in_id = $pdo->lastInsertId();`

If you use `mysqli_*` extension that's `$books_in_id = $mysqli->insert_id;`

**EDIT:** if you use the `mysql_*` version ( which is deprecated), upgrade first to mysqli_* , or check in the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php)

Answer (score 0):

Do you have to stick to mysql?  Because if you can use mysqli you can use multi_query(), which lets you execute multiple queries at once.
Link : http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.multiple-statement.php

Comment: This is still multiple queries. It is just a way to send them in one command to reduce the number of DB requests that you need to make. This wouldn't really provide any value to the OP.

Answer (score 0):

No,Its not possible with only one `INSERT` query.

You can follow these steps

1. Write two different queries and execute them
2. Create Stored Procedure that execute two INSERT queried

For point One you can use`LAST_INSERT_ID()` function to add foreigh key